Angular PrimeNG <p-columnFilter> UI breaks when filtering from TypeScript
I’m using Angular 18 with PrimeNG 17 and have a table with <p-columnFilter> components. Filtering through the UI works fine, but when I filter programmatically using the filter() function in TypeScript, the <p-columnFilter> UI breaks with the following error:

ERROR RuntimeError: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object
'[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to
Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe?

HTML:
<p-columnFilter
  field="name"
  matchMode="in"
  display="menu"
  [showMatchModes]="false"
  [showOperator]="false"
  [showAddButton]="false"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <div class="px-3 pt-3 pb-0">
      <span class="font-bold">Name</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
    <p-multiSelect
      [ngModel]="selectedNames"
      [options]="names"
      placeholder="Any"
      (onChange)="filter($event.value)"
      optionLabel="name"
    >
      <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
        <div class="inline-block vertical-align-middle">
          <span class="ml-1 mt-1">{{ option.name }}</span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-multiSelect>
  </ng-template>
</p-columnFilter>

TypeScript:
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.selectedNames = [{ name: 'James Butt' }];
  this.table?.filter(this.selectedNames, 'name', 'in');
}

Steps to reproduce:

Click on the filtering icon on the Name column to see the filteringUI.
Apply the filter programmatically in ngAfterViewInit().
Expected behavior: The <p-columnFilter> UI should remain functional even when
filtering is done programmatically.

Reproducer:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/gsfshm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-filter-advanced-demo.ts
I created an issue on Gitlab, does anyone knows when this error can come from ?
Thanks

The error is often triggered when changes are made to a binding after Angular has completed its initial change detection.
To resolve this, you can wrap the code inside ngAfterViewInit with setTimeout.
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedNames = [{ name: 'James Butt' }];
      this.table?.filter(this.selectedNames, 'name', 'in');
    }, 0);
  }

you can see an example on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/gsfshm-wrmtwe?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-filter-advanced-demo.html
